# Use User from FOSUserBundle with another Entity

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

When I create a User with FOSUserBundle UserManager and then I want to add it to different Entity like this:

```
$log = new Log();
$log->setOwner($user)
```

I get error that "A new entity was found through the relationship". It seems that `$user` that is created with `FOSUserBundle` UserManager is not seen by default EntityManager `($this->getDoctrine->getManager())` and it wants to add it to database. Previously it worked but with some recent `FOSUserBundle` update it stopped. Previously USer Manager could add User entity to Database and the EntityManager could add log Entity with a reference to User entity `($owner)`.

Any ideas what is going on and how to fix this?

Comment: Seems that you should persist the Log entity.  When are you performing the flush? The fos user manager is persisting the newly created user?

Comment: I create user $this->userManager->createUser(), set email etc. Then I add it to Log with $log->setOwner($user) then I persist Log and then make flush. If I use $this->userManager->updateUser($user, false); and then make flush for all I get above error. If I use $this->userManager->updateUser($user); User is saved and then EntityManager tries to add it again.

Comment: Have you tried to persist the user? I'm not sure if the manager does it by default.

Comment: Yes, it does. updateUser(UserInterface $user, $andFlush = true) persist the user always and flush it if second parameter is true.

Comment: @Carlos you are right. I should persist log first, then add user to id. Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the coments to your question.

First you should persiste the Log entity and then add the user to it as owner.